# run ADIS16465-1BMLZ on raspberry pi 4 with kuiper linux

Tags: raspberry-pi4, gyroscope, imu

How can I save data from ADIS16465-1BMLZ on raspberry pi 4 with kuiper Linux in a .CSV file for a specific period, let's say 5 minutes? Is this achievable?

I  connected the ADIS16465-1BMLZ module to the Raspberry Pi 4 using the EVAL-ADISIMU1-RPIZ board. To do this, I installed the Kuiper Linux operating system on the Raspberry Pi and ran the ADI IIO Oscilloscope software
I could run this sensor as follows blews link:
https://github.com/analogdevicesinc/iio-oscilloscope/issues/443
now i have question about how i can save data for period of time
How can I save data from ADIS16465-1BMLZ on raspberry pi 4 with kuiper Linux in a .CSV file for a specific period, let's say 5 minutes? Is this achievable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem was solved even though I could save data on certain periods and save it automatically on USB flash when it connects to the raspberry pi.
for this purpose, you need just some adjustments on config.txt and pyadi.iio library
if you need more help just let me know

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).